# How to integrate OpenCV with OpenGL (Visual C++ 2008)

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, opencv, glut

I have written two codes, using OpenCv (for marker detection) and OpenGL (for creating a simple 3D box). But I'm having no clue on how to integrate those two. ex: Displaying the box on a OpenCV window.

When i tried to call the following two functions of OpenCV and OpenGL, only OpenGL functions seem to be executing. (OpenGL window is only created, but now OpenCV one)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    initGL(argc, argv); // basic initialization steps for OpenGL
    glutMainLoop(); // shows 3D scene in a new window
    startOCV(); // shows camera stream in a new window
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> [glutMainLoop](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node14.html) enters the GLUT event processing loop. This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program. **Once called, this routine will never return**.

Your code will block on `glutMainLoop`, so you need to call `startOCV` before it.

And if `startOCV` blocks as well, you need to [run this function in a thread](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/MultithreadingTutorial.aspx) so that `main()` can go on and execute `glutMainLoop`.

**EDIT**::

But the right way to do is [the other way around](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1875): **copy OpenCV's image to an OpenGL texture** and render that to the **OpenGL window**.

Comment: +1. Still the same. I only get OpenCV windows now. No openGL ones. :(

Comment: This means that you also have some code inside `startOCV` that blocks. Maybe there's some loop there that is blocking, most probably if you are dealing with camera. **The solution is to use threads**. Start one for `startOCV` so it doesn't block the execution of `main()` so that `glutMainLoop` can be executed.

Comment: You're not forced to use GLUT (glutMainLoop) or startOCV neither. Use a framework that allows you to implement your own event loop (like GLFW) and do the OpenCV grunt work yourself.

Comment: Updated answer with reference on how to convert an OpenCV image to an OpenGL texture.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the latest OpenCV trunk. They integrate OpenGL in highgui (OCV display module). It may make your life easier, and solve the problem for you.

Don't forget that any trunk version can be buggy and a bit undocumented. The next official release is not yet planned.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and this is how I solved it. I had code for capturing camera stream which used OpenCV and run in infinite while  loop and animation that used openGL and glut- `glutMainLoop()`.

I put openCV code for capturing camera stream inside update function -and called `glutTimerFunc(TIMER_MS, update, 0)` in main. Both animation and camera stream are working now. However, it did slow down animation a bit.